# Sorting With Tuples and Intergers in the Same List

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, wildcard

I'm a python noob and I need some guidance on how to handle both tuples and intergers in a function. I need to sort a list that can be a mix of integers and tuples.

I want [11, 10, (12, 52)] to be read like [11, 10, 12] (taking the first tuple element and leaving the integers as are) and return [10, 11, (12, 52)] so obviously I can't go:

```
>>> sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

...because ints aren't subscriptable. I could write thirty lines of code and get it working but there must be a simpler solution?

Thanks for the help! I'll select a best answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: What if the data is `[12, 11, (10, 52)]`?

Comment: You already know about `key`, so just write a key function that returns the first item if the object is a tuple, or the value if it's a number.  This won't be "thirty lines of code" but one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how `key` is defined. If `x` is a tuple, use `x[0]` for comparison, else use `x` itself for comparison.

```
>>> a = [11, 10, (12, 52)]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, tuple) else x)
[10, 11, (12, 52)]
```

Comment: I just saw, the above is what @BrenBarn says in the comment below your question.

Comment: Thanks Thrustmaster! I was hoping to avoid the use of isinstance() but it is certainly better than error-checking. Yes, BrenBarn pointed it out as well.